# error from using a function as parameter in another function

Tags: c++

I've been trying to debug this C++ error for many hours over 2 days and unable to figure it out or find answers in searching. Can anyone help illuminate me how to fix this?

Error:

```
111:44: error: arithmetic on a pointer to the function type 'double (double, int)'
            return (principal * (pow((effective_rate + 1), years_elapsed)));
                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
```

Relevant code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

using std::ios; 
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

double effective_rate(double annual_rate, int num_times_compounded=0);
double balance(double annual_rate, double principal, double &years_elapsed, int num_times_compounded=0);

double annual_rate;
int num_times_compounded;
double principal;
double years_elapsed;

int main() {
 //code to get inputs and do printouts
}

double effective_rate(double annual_rate, int num_times_compounded) 
{
    if (num_times_compounded > 0) {
        return (pow((1 + (annual_rate/num_times_compounded)), num_times_compounded) - 1);
    }   else {
        return (pow(e, annual_rate) - 1);
    }
}

double balance(double annual_rate, double principal, double years_elapsed, int num_times_compounded)
{
    if (num_times_compounded > 0) {
[**this is line 111:**] return (principal * (pow((effective_rate + 1), years_elapsed)));
    } else {
        return (principal * (pow( (effective_rate + 1), num_times_compounded) ) );
    }
}
```

It appears that the second function does not see the first `effective_rate` function, and changing to pass by reference did not seem to work either. I must be missing something simple and obvious?

Comment: What do you mean (in your code) by `effective_rate + 1`? After all, `effective_rate` is a _function_, not a number.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the **function** using its parameters. You cannot call a function without using parentheses and its arguments (if it has) inside it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

double effective_rate(double annual_rate, int num_times_compounded=0);
double balance(double annual_rate, double principal, double years_elapsed, int num_times_compounded=0);

double annual_rate;
int num_times_compounded;
double principal;
double years_elapsed;

int main() {
 //code to get inputs and do printouts
}

double effective_rate(double annual_rate, int num_times_compounded) 
{
    if (num_times_compounded > 0) {
        return (pow((1 + (annual_rate/num_times_compounded)), num_times_compounded) - 1);
    }   else {
        return (pow(e, annual_rate) - 1);
    }
}

double balance(double annual_rate, double principal, double years_elapsed, int num_times_compounded)
{
    if (num_times_compounded > 0) {
        return (principal * (pow((effective_rate(annual_rate, num_times_compounded) + 1), years_elapsed)));
    } else {
        return (principal * (pow((effective_rate(annual_rate, num_times_compounded) + 1), num_times_compounded) ) );
    }
}
```

This will work but you need to define `e` first.

Also, you should avoid using globals as much as possible. In your case, you have conflicting names. For example, you are defining `annual_rate` and `num_times_compounded` as global variables **and** using those very same names as arguments of your functions. The global variables will not be used in those cases.

Edit: Oh and finally, you should also avoid using `using` directives. Typing `std::` doesn't take much effort and makes your code safer from dumb errors.

Edit: To answer OP's last question, you can use the ternary conditional operator but you sacrifice readability. The only other I can see it done it by using a third variable to store the result of the ternary conditional operation and then use that variable as the period.

```
double balance(double annual_rate, double principal, double years_elapsed, int num_times_compounded)
{
    return (principal * (pow((effective_rate(annual_rate, num_times_compounded) + 1), num_times_compounded > 0 ? years_elapsed : num_times_compounded)));
}
```

Or with the variable.. probably cleaner.

```
double balance(double annual_rate, double principal, double years_elapsed, int num_times_compounded)
{
    double period = num_times_compounded > 0 ? years_elapsed : num_times_compounded;
    return (principal * (pow((effective_rate(annual_rate, num_times_compounded) + 1), period )));
}
```

Comment: or simply use `exp(annual_rate)` instead ...

Comment: An effective rate is not just e^n. His function is actually correct.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur +1, but I think Martin's point is that you could use `std::exp(annual_rate)` instead of `std::pow(e,annual_rate)` (not instead of `effective_rate()`). Then you wouldn't have to define `e`.

Comment: Oh that's right. Missed that.

Comment: @jogojapan yes that's what I meant (typing on an stupid iPad, don't want to write too much :) ...)

Comment: Thank you all for your help. When I rewrite it so the functions such as balance are calculated only using the parameters in the function prototype, it works correctly. However, is there no way to call the function effective_rate within the balance function instead of replicating much of that code?

Comment: @user1797398: Added an answer to that question. Please give checkmark if you feel my answer has solved your problem.